# Deleting all charts in a worksheet. Error handling

Tags: excel, vba

I am using

```
Worksheets("Treatment failures - Graph").ChartObjects.Delete
```

to delete all charts within my worksheet. My issue is that I don't know how to error handle this for when there are no charts in the worksheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add a check to see if there are any charts on the sheet.

```vb
With Worksheets("Treatment failures - Graph").ChartObjects
    If .Count > 0 Then
        .Delete
    End If
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to ignore this error:

```
With Worksheets("Treatment failures - Graph")
    On Error Resume Next
    .ChartObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With
```

Comment: I wouldn't suggest this as it ignores all errors.  No charts on sheet or the sheet doesn't exist in the first place.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook You're right. Corrected the code